# How much pixels (width) will string in label take on iOS ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am interested to know how much pixels (width, space) will string take in label on iOS.
And string can be any length.

And I am not taking about monospaced fonts, for them I could use some heuristic.

I am talking about NOT monospaced fonts.
Problem is because "i" an "h" are not the same width.

I know that this is hard problem, but maybe somebody solved it somehow.
Even some approximations will be good for me.

Comment: what font and what font size do you have?

Comment: your real problem is, you have forgot to google after any solution before you asked... the `–boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` method would do the job for you, and you could have find thousand example of its usage.

Comment: @Touchpad best would be for any font and any size. As I said I know how to do it for monospaced font, when size is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From developer.apple.com:

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size
                   options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options
                attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
                   context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: